# Powershell Pattern, regex

Tags: regex, powershell, pattern-matching

What's the best way to use a script that reads the output of a file and then looks for a specific number and if that number is greater than it, sends an email. The line that it's reading has a lot of spaces after it. I have the below script but it's not working. It's saying the cannot index into null array `$Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[ <<<< 1].Value` It appears to be getting hung up on the regex and the match group. Do I need to change something? Why is it complaining about matches.group[1]? Or maybe even use a different approach to the solution. I'm up for changing the script if needed. I'm pretty stuck.

```
Script - 


 $Output = 'D:\test.data\QueuedJobss.txt'
d:
set-location -Path 'D:\program files\veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd'
.\bpdbjobs -summary -L > $Output

$Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value

if ($Queued -gt 0 ) {
      $MailArgs = @{
            'To'          = 'ab2112@test.com'
            'From'        = 'netbackup@test.com'
            'Subject'     = 'Over 100 Queued Jobs!'
            'Attachments' = $Output
            'Body'        = 'Check Environment'

            'SmtpServer' = 'smtp.us.test.com'
           }
         Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
      }
```

Output file it's reading - (Notice the spaces)

```
Summary of jobs on ustestnbma01
Queued:                                1
Waiting-to-Retry:                        0
Active:                           5
Successful:                   25876
Partially Successful:           136
Failed:                         327
Incomplete:                       0
Suspended:                        0
Total:                        26345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you regex to a look behind I think is the way to go. How is this:

```
$Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value
```

Comment: No groups in the regex - so no need. Have you tried it?

Comment: Ok that didn't error out this time. However I'm still not receiving an alert. Is `if ($Queued -gt 2 )` the proper command for it to say if number is greater than 2 then #send email

Comment: In your example data queued value is 1 which is not greater than 2

Comment: I also attempted to change it to -ge 0 and still no notification. https://imgur.com/1nijPMY

Comment: Debug your code, does code inside the if sratement execute? If so then it is probably the `Send-MailMessage` that is the issue. The way you are using it doesn't look right.

Comment: The code creates the file...the send-mailmessage is the same as I use in other scripts that work.

Comment: I have answered your question, if you want me to fix all your code I can supply my daily rate.

Comment: This has been fixed by using [int] at the beginning of $Queued